# Buttons duplicating but action works

Tags: php, sql

My code displays all data from my column `workouts` with the status "to_do" but it also duplicates the `submit_abs` button in the modal. [This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQFvo.png)

Clicking a button updates the status correctly.

```
  <?php # start of first php code

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM workouts WHERE w_traineeid = '$id' AND w_status = 'to_do'";

        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultChecks = mysqli_num_rows($results);

        if ($resultChecks > 0) {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) # end of first php code  
            {
              ?>
        <a href="php/mgmmsEditWO.php?id=<?php echo $row['w_traineeid']?>" class="btn btn-md" type="submit" id="submit_abs" name="submit_abs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Confirm" style="background-color:#ecf0f1; color:black " ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
            <?php
            }
         } 
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that there are multiple buttons is because you are creating them in a loop. Remove the `while` loop & you will only get one button:

```
  <?php # start of first php code

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM workouts WHERE w_traineeid = '$id' AND w_status = 'to_do'";
        /*$sql = "SELECT * FROM workouts";*/
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultChecks = mysqli_num_rows($results);

        if ($resultChecks > 0) {  # end of first php code  
              ?>
        <a href="php/mgmmsEditWO.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" class="btn btn-md" type="submit" id="submit_abs" name="submit_abs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Confirm" style="background-color:#ecf0f1; color:black " ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
            <?php
        } 
     ?>
```

You are currently checking if the number of rows in `$results` is more than 0 & then adding a button for each row.

Comment: I remove it but it fails to update the status here is my code<?php
 session_start();
 include 'connection.php';
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 


 $sql = "UPDATE workouts SET w_status =  'done'
   WHERE w_traineeid = '$id';";
      
      mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                  alert('Workout Successfully Updated!');
                        window.location.replace('http://localhost/woportal/mgmstwp.php');
                  </script>";
        exit();
?>

Comment: @renzcp, `$row` is no longer available because of the loop being removed. Please check the edited code.